# lightning-record-edit-form doesn't update

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

This is my HTML code, pressing the update button does not register any error and the data shown are the old ones. Any ideas why it would not work? A few days ago it worked without problems.

```
                        <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId}
                                object-api-name="DCABM_obj_sol__c">
                                <lightning-messages>
                                </lightning-messages>
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                                    <div class="slds-col">
                                        <lightning-input-field
                                            field-name="DCABM_fld_name__c">
                                        </lightning-input-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col">
                                        <lightning-input-field
                                            field-name="DCABM_fld_sName__c">
                                        </lightning-input-field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                                    <div class="slds-col">
                                        <lightning-input-field
                                            field-name="DCABM_fld_email__c">
                                        </lightning-input-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col">
                                        <lightning-input-field
                                            field-name="DCABM_fld_user__c">
                                        </lightning-input-field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                    <lightning-button
                                        class="slds-m-top_small
                                        slds-p-right_xx-small"
                                        onclick={handleControllerChanges}
                                        variant="neutral"
                                        name="cancel"
                                        label="cancel">
                                    </lightning-button>
                                    <lightning-button
                                        class="slds-m-top_small
                                        slds-p-left_xx-small"
                                        onclick={updateUserData}
                                        variant="brand"
                                        type="submit"
                                        name="update"
                                        label="update">
                                    </lightning-button>
                                </div>
                            </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Comment: can you add your Javascipt code?

Comment: You don't need JS code, it's lightning data @PranayJaiswal

Comment: i think he refers especially to updateUserData (but also other potential clashes in e. g. hooks) - submit type is already invoking an action but you have a handler on top

Comment: Ah, updateUserData is just an dispatchEvent @Renji-xD

Comment: maybe check the developer tools and see if you discover sth. in the actual network request / response or enable to pause on exceptions and see if sth is thrown somewhere. Otherwise If you are saying you have nothing special in your controller i think you have to request sfdc for support as nobody here has your object / user / permissions etc. to give much more hints - your shared code looks fine and therefore its hard for externals to comment on it

Comment: Deleting the "onclick" event of the "submit" button it's works perfectly @Renji-xD

Comment: ya i mean submit buttons have a different behavior than normal buttons (one of the reasons we asked for the code) which i guess clashes other stuff - but then i guess you have your solution. if you want to dispatch a event i think the edit-form component fires a success event which you can handle via onsuccess

Comment: Yes I used the "onsuccess" of the form. The "updateUserData" just had this code:  window.console.log("update");
        this.controller= true;
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Update',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        ); @Renji-xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the "onclick" event of the "submit" button it's works perfectly